# Google Search box for paginated place search

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using `Google's` `SearchBox for autocompleting`

I tried the following link and works fine.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

But there is no pagination mentioned for the `SearchBox`.

Pagination is mentioned for `NearBy Search`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search-pagination.

How can I implement the same in `SearchBox place search`

Comment: Have you found an answer for this??